# How can i add additional Data(Type) to chart.js

Tags: chart.js

i had already done adding a click handler to each Segment of my doughnut chart with adding the following Code :

```
$("#myChart").click( 
function(evt){
var activePoints = myNewChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
var chartelementid = activePoints[0].label;
alert(chartelementid);
//$('.details div').css("display", "none");
//$('#' + chartelementid).show();
}
);
```

This works fine, when finished it should display an additional Div with Details for this segment.
Unfortunality my labels are more then just Single Words, so i'm struggeling to create div ID's with the same name...

My Idea is to add to every Segment an additional Data like value,label, etc. so it could be an ID. but if i just add the ID information to the Segment it will not exist as variable.

Add DataType:

```
var dataImprove = [   
{
value: 30,
color:"#001155",
highlight: "#1c2f7c",
label: "KnowHow Erhalt / Transfer & Aufbau",
id:"test"
}
]
```

where can i add in chart.js an additional dataType like shown above my ID to be accessible in the DOM?

kind regards Marco

Comment: already found : between line 999 and 1023 in chart.js before drawing - i've added the line **id: ChartElements[0].id,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already found : between line 999 and 1023 in chart.js before drawing - i've added the line

**id: ChartElements[0].id,**

so the Data with the name ID is in the DOM avaiable.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative pass a JSON string as your label, then intercept to render. For example:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    var d = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(d).Pie(json, {
        segmentStrokeWidth: 1,
        tooltipTemplate: "<%=label%>", //default the label
        customTooltips: function (tooltip) {

            // Hide if no tooltip
            if (!tooltip) {
                return;
            }
            var tooltipObj = JSON.parse(tooltip.text);
            // etc
```